# language of betrothal at wedding

Tags: halacha, minhag, wedding, kiddushin-eirusin

Traditionally, before a husband betroths his wife he says, "Harei at mekudeshet li btabaat zo kdat moshe vyisrael."

Is this language necessary in halacha or standardized by tradition (minhag)? If not necessary, what are the required ingredients for the statement to be halachically binding?

Comment: Traditionally he says "zo" not "zu". "Zu" means "which" while "zo" means "this". I assume he doesn't want to be saying "I betroth you with which ring?"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That specific formulation is certainly not necessary. The Gemara ([Kiddushin 5a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=5&format=pdf)) has several variant formulations:

> כיצד בכסף? נתן לה כסף או שוה כסף ואמר לה "הרי את מקודשת לי", "הרי את מאורסת לי", "הרי את לי לאינתו"-- הרי זו מקודשת
>
> How does [betrothal through] money work? He gives her money or monetary equivalent and says to her "הרי את מקודשת לי" (behold you are betrothed to me) or "הרי את מאורסת לי" (behold you are betrothed to me) or "הרי את לי לאינתו" (behold you are a woman/wife to me), behold she is betrothed.

The Gemara on 5b adds some more examples:

> ת"ר הרי את אשתי הרי את ארוסתי הרי את קנויה לי מקודשת הרי את שלי הרי את ברשותי הרי את זקוקה לי מקודשת

The "הרי את" (behold you) formulation can also be dropped, as we see on [Kiddushin 13a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=13&format=pdf):

> אמר לה כנסי סלע זו שאני חייב ליכי וחזר ואמר לה התקדשי לי בו בשעת מתן מעות רצתה מקודשת לא רצתה אינה מקודשת
>
> If he said to her "take this selah that I owe you" and then said "התקדשי לי בו" (become betrothed to me through it), and she is appeased, she is betrothed...

In fact, the Gemara (6a) concludes that if they had been generally discussing her becoming betrothed, and then he gave her *kiddushin*, she is betrothed:

> תנן היה מדבר עם אשה על עסקי גיטה וקידושיה ונתן לה גיטה וקידושיה ולא פירש ר' יוסי אומר דיו ר' יהודה אומר צריך לפרש ואמר רב הונא אמר שמואל הלכה כר' יוסי

What doesn't work is if he phrases it to be about him becoming the husband as opposed to her becoming betrothed/wife, as we see on 5a:

> "הריני אישך", "הריני בעליך", "הריני ארוסיך"-- אין כאן בית מיחוש
>
> "Behold I am your husband", "behold I am your husband (with a different Hebrew word)", "behold I am your betrothed" - these are not even a concern [of betrothal].

As far as the codified halacha is concerned, Shulchan Aruch [Even HaEzer 27:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7602) rules that any language which unquestionably implies betrothal in that locale, such as the examples from the above gemaras, suffices (as long as she comprehends the implication), or any language which universally implies betrothal even if she doesn't understand. The Rema adds that ideally one should use the formulation with which we are familiar, including the "כדת משה וישראל" part.

> **בְּכֶסֶף כֵּיצַד, נוֹתֵן לָהּ בִּפְנֵי שְׁנַיִם פְּרוּטָה אוֹ שְׁוֵה פְּרוּטָה, וְאוֹמֵר לָהּ: ''הֲרֵי אַתְּ מְקֻדֶּשֶׁת לִי בָּזֶה**''.  הַגָּה: וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁיֵּשׁ לוֹמַר לָהּ: ''כְּדַת משֶׁה וְיִשְׂרָאֵל''  (כָּל בּוֹ).   וְכֵן נוֹהֲגִין לְכַּתְחִילָה ....  **וְהוּא הַדִּין אִם אָמַר לָהּ: ''הֲרֵי אַתְּ מְאֹרֶסֶת לִי'', אוֹ ''הֲרֵי אַתְּ לִי לְאִשָּׁה'', וְכֵן בְּכָל לָשׁוֹן שֶׁמַּשְׁמָעוּתוּ לְשׁוֹן קִדּוּשִׁין וַדַּאי בְּאוֹתוֹ מָקוֹם, וּבִלְבַד שֶׁהִיא תָּבִין שֶׁהוּא לְשׁוֹן קִדּוּשִׁין, וְאִם הָיָה מְדַבֵּר עִמָּהּ תְּחִלָּה עַל עִסְקֵי קִדּוּשִׁין, וְנָתַן לָהּ אֲפִלּוּ בִּשְׁתִיקָה, הָוֵי קִדּוּשִׁין... וְכָל שֶׁכֵּן אִם אָמַר לְשׁוֹן קִדּוּשִׁין וַדַּאי, אֶלָּא שֶׁאֵינָהּ מְבִינָה אוֹתוֹ, דַּהֲווּ קִדּוּשִׁין**