# Why do we say Harei At Mekudeshes Li ... "k'Das Moshe v'Yisrael"?

Tags: halacha, marriage, kiddushin-eirusin

Why do we have this "*k'Das Moshe v'Yisrael*" addendum?

To my knowledge we don't really say this by other *mitzvos* so why do we say it here/ what's it adding?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68184/language-of-betrothal-at-wedding?r=SearchResults

Comment: @GershonGold Thanks! Saw this- it answers that *k'daas Moshe v'Yisrael* wouldn't be *me'akeiv* but doesn't really answer my question- namely, that why specifically by *kiddushin* we have this lingo, but not by other *mitzvos*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Tosafos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tosafot) in several places explain that we say *k'das Moshe v'yisrael* by marriage because marriage is effective contingent upon the approval of the Sages. In [certain instances](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95979/what-is-a-halachic-annulment-of-a-marriage-and-when-is-it-employed/95982#95982) where the Sages disapprove of certain actions, they render the marriage as if it had never occurred.

[**Gittin 33a (My emphasis)**](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=33&format=pdf)

> ומי איכא מידי דמדאורייתא בטל גיטא ומשום מה כח ב"ד יפה שרינן אשת איש לעלמא אין **כל דמקדש אדעתא דרבנן מקדש ואפקעינהו רבנן לקידושין מיניה** אמר ליה רבינא לרב אשי תינח דקדיש בכספא קדיש בביאה מאי איכא למימר שויוה רבנן לבעילתו בעילת זנות
>
> And is
> it possible then, that where a Get is according to the Written Law cancelled we should, to save the
> authority of the Beth din, [declare it valid and] so allow a married woman to marry another? — Yes.
> **When a man betroths a woman, he does so under the conditions laid down by the Rabbis, and in this
> case the Rabbis annul his betrothal.** Said Rabina to R. Ashi: This is quite right if the husband had
> originally betrothed his wife with money. But if he had betrothed her by the act of marriage,
> what can we say? — The Rabbis declared the act of marriage to be retrospectively nonmarital. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nashim/Gittin.pdf))

**Tosafos s.v. *Kol* (commenting on the emphasized words above)**

> ולכך אומר בשעת קידושין כדת משה וישראל
>
> And therefore we say at the time of the marriage "in accordance with the law of Moses and Israel".

Note that in the text of a *Get* the same phrase appears, as recorded by [Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) in [Hilchos Gerushin 4:12](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=3466):

> ודן די יהוי ליכי מנאי ספר תרוכין וגט פטורין ואגרת שבוקין כדת משה וישראל
>
> This will serve you as a bill of divorce, a get dismissing you, and a letter releasing you, from me, according to the faith of Moses and Israel. ([Touger translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/957709/jewish/Gerushin-Chapter-Four.htm))

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a sound *svara* and thanks for refreshing my memory about "ואפקעינהו רבנן לקידושין מיניה" (I think there's also a Tosfos in the beginning of *kesuvos* about ואפקעינהו)

Comment: @alicht You're welcome. The same Talmudic passage appears in several places, one of them being Kesuvos 3a. Tosafos there makes the same comment.

Comment: follow up question- why exactly is כל דמקדש אדעתא דרבנן מקדש? Why does this principle exist? Is it *d"oraisa* or *d'rabanan*?

Comment: @alicht Check out the post I linked in my answer. If that doesn’t help you, you should post a new question detailing what specifically you’re looking for that’s not covered by that question.

Comment: Thanks! Just asked it in a separate question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/why-is-marriage-effective-contingent-upon-the-approval-of-the-sages