# Origin of the word dati (דָּתִי)

Tags: words, hebrew, language

Is there any Talmudic sources that claim the origin of the Hebrew word “dati” (דָּתִי) comes from the Avestan word daena?

Comment: Is this on-topic? Not all questions about Hebrew are accepted here; can you [edit] to clarify how this pertains to Judaism as a religion?

Comment: @DonielF I edited my question so could you please take my question off of being marked as a duplicate question.

Comment: I didn’t mark it as a dupe, nor do I have the ability to remove it myself; it needs five votes from the community or a moderator to reopen it. Nevertheless, I’m struggling to see how this isn’t a duplicate, as both ask about the etymology of the word דת.

Answer (score 3):

דָּתִי is a recent coinage; its first attestation listed by the [Hebrew Language Academy](https://maagarim.hebrew-academy.org.il/Pages/PMain.aspx?koderekh=100567&page=1) is from 1851, so there is no possibility of a Talmudic source on it.

The word is an adjective derived from the noun דָּת, which is much older, appearing already in the Bible in Esther (its Aramaic equivalent is also used in Ezra and Daniel). In the earlier books, it's entirely absent (if we follow the ketiv in Deuteronomy 33:2). The [generally](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Klein_Dictionary%2C_%D7%93%D6%B8%D6%BC%D7%AA.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)-[accepted](https://archive.org/stream/GeseniusHebrewChaldeeLexiconOldTestamentScriptures.tregelles.1857.24/04.GesenHebChalLexOTS.Daleth.Tregelles1857.ggle.msft.#page/n27/mode/2up) [etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%AA) is a loan word from Persian (dāt, dād, "law, justice").

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68565/170